# Enable scroll with CTRL + middle mouse click instead of link redirection

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, anchor, anchor-scroll

Is there a way to enable scroll with the middle mouse button (aka mouse 3) when CTRL (or some other key) were pressed together; instead of the default behavior which is redirection to the href in a new tab?

https://jsfiddle.net/b7zyx39f/

**My code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800"></a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800"></a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent the middle click and prevent the default action using the `auxevent` ([see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/auxclick_event)). But in your case I suggest to remove the `href` of the `a` tag and add an attribute `data-href` for the link. Then add a on click listener for those `a` tags which will redirect to the desired link. An example might be,

```html
<a data-href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800"></a>
```

and in javascript

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(href => {
  href.addEventListener("click", e => {
    window.location.href = href.dataset.href;
  });
});
```

To capture the ctrl button you may add another event listener for redirecting on middle click if ctrl is not pressed

```js
href.addEventListener("auxclick", e => {
  if (!window.event.ctrlKey) {
    window.open(href.dataset.href, '_blank');
  }
});
```

Comment: SO condemns comments like a thanks, but had to... Thank you so much, you're a genius! <3